# Remove Black Square on Select CSS

Tags: css

**Edit:**

I found out that this square is actually a part of the scroll bar, and that by putting:

```
select::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

It does not appear.

<strike>I have a select. When I am not focused on it, it looks normal:
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REIF2.png)</strike>

However, when I focus on it, this strange black square in the top left corner shows up: [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16wYy.png)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here's my code if it helps:

```
<style>
html {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

select option {
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<select size="2">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: add `input:focus{
    outline: none;
}` to whatever element it is

Comment: @dustytrash Tried that, still shows the black square...

Comment: Try changing your `select` to `select, select:focus` as well as adding `* focus { outline: none; } `

Answer (score 1):

Set the following to your box

```
outline: none !important;
```

Comment: @Juniorized Make sure your browser isn't getting a cache'd version. Otherwise you'll have to post your HTML to get answers

Comment: @dustytrash Yes, it's not a cached version, it's a local file, I have posted my HTML, and I've had outline: none on my box since I started.

Comment: @Juniorized Which browser are you using? I can't recreate the issue on chrome/FF/IE

Answer (score 0):

Your select code is clean.

It should be something in your html that causing it. It can be other css or javascript.

You can wrap your select element using some clearfix class to make it clean but you have to inspect your html to search for the problem.

```css
html {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

select option {
  padding: 10px;
}

.clearfix:before {
  content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
<select size="2">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these to the element

```
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
              -o-transition: none !important;
                 transition: none !important;
```